# In laravel 5.5 middleware modifications are not saved to database

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

In laravel 5.5 I want to make work out for my string values when submitting the form.

For this I created Middleware app/Http/Middleware/WorkTextString.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Http\Traits\funcsTrait;
use function PHPSTORM_META\type;

class WorkTextString
{

    use funcsTrait;
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->name = $this->workTextString($request->name); // Fields I want to modify
        $request->description = $this->workTextString($request->description);

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function workTextString($str) // my workout for any string
    { // some string routing, like trimming more 2 spaces inside of string
    ...
```

and in app/Http/Kernel.php I added my Middleware :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'WorkTextString'=>\App\Http\Middleware\WorkTextString::class,
];
```

In routes/api.php :

```
Route::group([  'prefix' => '/v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\V1', 'as' => 'api.'], function () {

    Route::resource('user_task_types', 'UserTaskTypesController', ['except' => ['create', 'edit']])->middleware('WorkTextString');
```

as I see my Middleware is triggered, but modifications are not saved to db.
Which is the right way ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the title, is not clear what you are asking for. Also show your `workTextString()` definition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to update data in the request. You could try merging in the new data:

```
$request->merge([
    'name' => $this->workTextString($request->name),
    'description' => $this->workTextString($request->description),
]);
```

Or

```
$request['name'] = $this->workTextString($request->name);
$request['description'] = $this->workTextString($request->description);
```

`Request` doesn't have a `__set` method so you aren't actually setting any variable on what is actually being used as the input source when trying to set a property, `$request->name = ...`;

Though still not sure what part of the code you have has to do with the DB.